# when I filter a frame with "fps=fps=30" my code starts consuming a lot of ram until it crashes, but if I use "scale=250:250" it works fine

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-processing, libav

When I apply the filter "scale=250:250" my code works, it outputs a rescalated video
but when I apply the filter "fps=fps=30000/1000", the code asks for ram until it crashes, I think the problem is in the applyFilter function
PasteBin of complete code https://pastebin.com/tcgwFmTz this part starts at line 257

```c
int applyFilter(filterCtx* filter, AVFrame* inFrame, AVFrame* outFrame)
{
    int ret;
    /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
    if (av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(filter->buffersrc_ctx, inFrame, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF) < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
    for (EVER)
    {
        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(filter->buffersink_ctx, outFrame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```c
    char filterDesc = "fps=fps=30000/1000"; // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    //char filterDesc = "scale=1200:1200"; THIS WORKS
    filter = initFilter(filterDesc, params);
    
    for (EVER)
    {
        getFrame(decoder, frame, packet);
        if(decoder->container->streams[packet->stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            if (filter != NULL)
            {
                response = applyFilter(filter, frame, filterFrame);
                if (response < 0)
                {
                    printf("Error while applying a filter");
                    return -1;
                }
                tmp = frame;
                av_frame_unref(frame);
                frame = filterFrame;
                filterFrame = tmp;
                if(response == 3)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            
        }
        encode(decoder, encoder, frame, packet->stream_index);

    }
```

Comment: Just a guess: is there a typo? `fps=fps=`  -> `fps=` ???

Comment: I tried with both, they have the same behaviour

Comment: In your second code block, you're _not_ showing how `frame` is initialized. From https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/av_buffersink_get_frame/cpp-av_buffersink_get_frame-function-examples.html ... Do you need: `av_frame_free(&frame);` after the `av_frame_unref` call?

Comment: From those [related] lines, I'm not sure if the frame pointer(s) swap code is correct/valid. I can't tell for sure [without more code], but are you leaking a frame?

Comment: In this example, he mallocs the frame every time he applys the filter, that's why he then free's the frame, I don't, I just unref , and ref again when needed, the only thing that I malloc in this chunk of code is in encode, I malloc a packet that then I free, I think my problem is in the apply filter function , because if I comment the if statement the code also works fine, I would love to show more of the code but stack over flow doesn't allow it, and I already croped a lot of the code that is in the for loop (:.

Comment: In `applyFilter`, you're returning 0 if it detects `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` [or `AVERROR_EOF`]. In either case, the output frame isn't valid [AFAICT]. But, you're still calling `enocde` regardless.

Comment: You are right, I changed it, but unfortunately, I have the same error

Comment: I'd edit your question and post the updated code. And, maybe the `av_frame_alloc` [and related] calls. It could be a bit tricky to catch the right call, but I'd run it under `gdb` and put a breakpoint on `malloc` [et. al.] to see who/when is asking for more memory. See: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing__decoding_8c_source.html It _stops_ on `EAGAIN` or `EOF`!?!?

Comment: You're _only_ calling `av_frame_unref` _if_ it's a video packet. Do you need to call [just] it for an audio packet [just to release it]?

Comment: At the begining of the getFrame function I also unref the audio\video frame. I've been debugging with microsoft visual studio, but the code of the libav api is hard to understand since i'm new to programming I printed addres the frame pointer where pointing to and they don't change, I editied the question and added a Paste bin of the complete file, it's a bit long and messy, the most similar thing in the documentation is this https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c

Comment: I had downloaded your [full] code and cleaned it up so it would build on my [linux] system. It _definitely_ is leaking memory. I could tell by performance and I added `mtrace`. The trace reports that it's in the AV libs--which doesn't [yet] relate to _which_ lib call your code is making [or _not_ making] that causes this. I'm analyzing things using some custom tools I have in my personal debug arsenal. I'm working backwards and will let you know when I find something definitive.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for taking the time but, I fortunatly found the problem. github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c this is the documentation example, I found out that av_buffersink_get_frame() sometimes outputs more than one frame and to fix this you have to loop over that funtion until it outputs an int < 0 this is how the final code looks like, https://pastebin.com/QFDwxAqj

Comment: the documentation example can't higher nor lower the framerate, of the video, or I couldn't make it work,the new pastebin I added doesn't leak memory but doesn't change the framerate.

Comment: I can't edit my previus comment, but you should loop until av_buffersink_get_frame() outputs AVERROR(EAGAIN) or AVERROR_EOF, not < 0